# How to get rid of geolocation info on linux?

Tags: vpn, geolocation, openvpn

First of all: I HAVE read the "Why does Google know my location?" posts but still in my case it is a bit weird / the solutions cannot fit.

The Setting:

- Fresh installed linux. Never ever logged in into a google-account or something like that on that machine.
- VPN using OpenVPN. Working according to those "show me information to my IP" - sites
- Location Services Disabled in Chrome browser

Still: Netflix displays "not available in your country" and google maps still displays my position (roughly)

I know about the possibilities for google to save my Routers MAC etc. but the following is also true for my network:

- Netflix does NOT recognize me when connecting via Windows-PC
- Also not when connecting via Android- Device (with disabled gps)
  (All devices use the same VPN and the same LAN)

So there must be something "in the machine" / the OS that offers Netflix the geo information it needs.

Any idea what this could be? And especially: How to avoid that / fake it? (I would be fine if the OS also is tricked about my location)

It is a clean Ubuntu installation with only XBMC installed if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The Linux system uses IPv6 while my Windows System isn't.

Also the Test-Sites I checked only checked the IPv4 - Adress telling me everything is right

Comment: And that doesn't get tunnelled?

Comment: Nope. Was surprised, too